# Example of a function f(x), where f(0)=0, f'(0)=∞, f'(x)>0, f(x)→1 for x→∞

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for a simple example of a strictly increasing, differentiable function $f(x)$, where $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=\infty$, $f(x)\to 1$ for $x\to \infty$.

Comment: What does $\;f'(0)=\infty\;$ mean? Is $\;x=0\;$ a vertical asymptote ?

Comment: $\sqrt{x}/(1+\sqrt{x})$?

Answer (score 3):

You could take 
$$f(x)=\frac{x^\alpha}{1+x^{\alpha}}$$
for any $0<\alpha<1$

Answer (score 2):

what about $\dfrac{\sqrt x}{1 + \sqrt x}?$